# why my coalesce function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have Query:

```
SELECT   Stage1
        ,Stage2
        ,Stage3 
FROM dbo.Cases
WHERE Number='6913'
```

result:

```
Stage1  Stage2      Stage3
==========================
NULL    Settlement  Stage1
```

But when i try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Stage1 ,Stage2 ,Stage3) AS [Exit]
FROM   dbo.Cases
WHERE  Number = '6913'
```

result still NULL:

```
EXIT    
====
NULL
```

Why it is coming like this, result supposed to be 'Settlement'

Please anybody can help????

Comment: Are you sure it's null, as opposed to an empty string?

Comment: This may be what Andrew means but ... check that your NULL is an actual NULL and not the nvarchar 'NULL' (i.e. select * from Cases where Stage1 = 'NULL' ). This has caught me out before.

Comment: It wouldn't be an empty string.  It might be the string null.  To troubleshoot, add another column to your query, nvl(stage1, 'value is null'), or 'before ' || Stage1, || ' after'

Comment: Hi every one, thanks for the reply. Is there any alternate way to sort this out.  I mean how to implement COALESCE function?.please help me with this

Comment: Coalesce will return the first non-null value in the choices you give it.  If your Stage1 column has a value in it ('NULL' or whatever) then coalesce will return it.  So I guess the short answer is, coalesce won't work for what you're describing.

Comment: @ Andrew, thanks for the reply..@MDiesel gave me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of for that is that you have the string value of NULL in your Stage1 field.  See if this query returns your row to determine if that is the case:

```
SELECT   Stage1
        ,Stage2
        ,Stage3 
FROM dbo.Cases
WHERE Number='6913'
AND Stage1 = 'NULL'
```

If it is a string value of NULL you could try this:

```
SELECT   COALESCE(NULLIF(Stage1, 'NULL'), NULLIF(Stage2, 'NULL'), NULLIF(Stage3, 'NULL'))           
FROM dbo.Cases
WHERE Number='6913'
```

Comment: what should i do if it is string value of NULL in my Stage1 field. I mean how to implement COALESCE function??is there any alternate way

Comment: I would actually make the value NULL via an update statement, but you could also use a case statement (that would get kinda ugly because you would need to check if the value was 'NULL' or NULL.  I'll edit my sql above to show you an example

Comment: I got values with above query. i think it is string NULL

Comment: Try the second query above to see if that works for you

Comment: Heh. Got the right answer first, but in the comments, second with the answer. Yet to have an answer accepted on SO in 5 years. Guess I'll have to wait a few more.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the value is an actual NULL and not the varchar value 'NULL'.

You can do this with:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Cases WHERE Stage1 IS NULL

SELECT * FROM dbo.Cases WHERE Stage1 = 'NULL'
```

And see what comes back.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks. Rushing too fast. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other things you can do to remove NULLS.

Filter out nulls:

```
SELECT   Stage1
        ,Stage2
        ,Stage3 
FROM dbo.Cases
WHERE Number='6913'
  AND State1 IS NOT NULL
```

or place and empty string when Stage1 is null:

```
SELECT   ISNULL(Stage1, '')
        ,Stage2
        ,Stage3 
FROM dbo.Cases
WHERE Number='6913'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i want replace Null to next stage value

Answer (score 0):

I have the same strange behavior.  I think the problem is not with the COALESCE() function, but with the value in the attribute/column.

In my case, the value appears to be NULL, and the way the data flows, it should be NULL. However, neither the Postgres WHERE clause or the COALESCE() function interprets the value as NULL.  I don't truly know what the value is.

My kluge solution is to take the MD5 hash of the value, and use the MD5 in my query logic.  I don't truly know what the real/internal value of the attribute is, but we can calculate the MD5 hash and use it as a proxy.

```
, COALESCE(
          CASE WHEN md5(value1) <> 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' THEN value1 ELSE NULL END
        , CASE WHEN md5(value2) <> 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' THEN value2 ELSE NULL END
        , CASE WHEN md5(value3) <> 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' THEN value3 ELSE NULL END
    ) AS desired_value
```